# Solve this equation, having problem with logarithm law?

Tags: logarithms

$$5^x + 3= 8 - 3 \times 5^x$$

Could you please help me? I do not know how I can use the logarithm here.
I basically tried to use different logarithm laws, but they are only for multiplication and not for addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4\times 5^x = 5 \iff 5^x=5/4 \iff x=\frac{\log(5/4)}{\log 5}=1-\frac{2\log 2}{\log 5}$$

Comment: I know this law, but i do not know how it could help me solving this equation.

Comment: The solution to your equation is $x=\log(5/4)/\log 5$.

Comment: Yeah the solution is right, but how did you simplified the equation to 4 x 5^x=5?

Comment: Add $3\times 5^x$ to both sides and subtract $3$ from both sides

Comment: Thanks mate I understood it.